# Is this version of proof that $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$ (Spivak) rigorous?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I am currently studying Spivak's calculus. Spivak provides the proof of Theorem 7-2 (A related question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/465210/137035).):

> If $f$ is continous on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is bounded above on $[a,b]$.

I can understand his proof strategy but I cannot understand all of his steps. So I have written my version of his proof as seen below:

> **Lemma 1**: If f is continous at $a$, then there is a number $\delta>0$ such that $f$ is bounded above on the interval $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$
>
> **Lemma 2**: If $\lim_{x \to a^-}f(x)=f(a)$, then there is a $\delta>0$ such that $f$ is bounded above on the set $\{x:a-\delta<x\leq a\}$

(I have proved these lemmas, I don't have problem with them.)

> **Proof:** Let $A= \{x:a\le x \le b \text{ and } f \text{ is bounded above on } [a,x]\}$. $A \neq \emptyset$ because at least $a \in A$ and $b$ is an upper bound of $A$. From the least upper bound axiom we know that $A$ has a least upper bound. Let us call it $\alpha$. Suppose that $\alpha<b$. From Lemma 1 we know that if $f$ is continous at $\alpha$, then $f$ is bounded on the interval $(\alpha-\delta,\alpha+\delta)$. Hence there are other values such as $x_0$ satisfying $\alpha<x_0<\alpha+\delta$ and $x_0 \in A$. This contradicts with the definition of the least upper bound and leaves us the only possibility $\alpha=b$. Although $\alpha=b$, $f$ may or may not be bounded above at $b$. But from Lemma 2, we know that $f$ is bounded above on the interval $(b-\delta,b]$ for $\delta>0$. This concludes our proof that $f$ is bounded above on $[a,b]$.

Is this version of proof rigorous enough? Does it contain any mistakes and flaws? *(I would appreciate any opinion and suggestion, because I am studying on my own and I want to learn things right.)*

Comment: It looks fine to me. Are you familiar with the notion of compactness?

Comment: This proof works.

Comment: @copper.hat No, never met before.

Comment: @Crostul It has come to my attention that I accepted $a \in A$ in the beginning (Because Spivak did so.). But shouldn't it be better if I use the right side version of Lemma 2 to conclude that $a \in A$. Because we can't know if f(a) is bounded above.

Comment: $f(a)$ is a real number, so it is bounded above by itself.

Comment: @Crostul Yes, that's a good point thank you.